# Bootstrap Datepicker - trigger enter event before datepicker is closed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, datepicker

When editing date manually inside input field and the date is not valid the input field is left empty. What I am trying to do is to trigger enter event before datepicker is closed. (Not sure if this is the right way to prevent the input field to be empty). In this case the datepicker would validate the date and inserted the current date. My code:

```
        $('#js-filter-input-date-from').datepicker({  
            onClose:function(dateText, inst){
                var e = $.Event('keypress');
                e.which = 13;
                $('#js-filter-input-date-from').trigger(e);
            }
        });
```

EDITED:
I have also tried this code but it doesn't seems to work either.

```
    $('#js-filter-input-date-from').on('blue dp.change', function(e){
        e.which = 13;
        $('#js-filter-input-date-from').trigger(e);
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to show datepicker again ?

Comment: Yes, I have datepicker in the input field date_from and then another date picker shows on date_to when date_from closes

Comment: try
`$('#js-filter-input-date-from').datepicker({  
            onClose:function(dateText, inst){
                $('#otherdatepicker-ID').datapicker('show');
            }
        });`

Comment: It opens the datepicker on date_to but leaves the input field (date_from) blank. There is no problem when I select the date from datepicker. The problem is when I try to change the date directly manually inside the input field and the date is not valid. Then it leaves the input field empty

Comment: Is there a way on blur to insert into input field the current date selected in the datepicker?